# Need to verify user landed on correct page after login?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm testing this on my local system and trying to verify user is successfully logged in and landed on correct page. 
Getting error when trying to compare String data with webelement data.

```
`package wnsautomation;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
//import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\orange\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriverWait myWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        String baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.52:9000";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        myWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/div/input")));

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/div/input")).sendKeys("admin@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div/div/input")).sendKeys("8JXzwRs4VWeGP0Sy");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[5]/button")).click();
        String expectedtext="Summary";
        WebElement actualtext;

        actualtext = driver.findElement(By.linkText("/html/body/div[3]/div/ng-include/div/div/div[1]/div/h3"));


           if (actualtext.contentEquals(expectedtext)){
                System.out.println("User succesfully loggedIN");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid credtendials!!");
            }



    }
}`
```

Comment: But i don't want to verify login with page title. There is text written on header 'Summary' through this text i want to do user validation as well as user landed on correct page.

Comment: please edit your question to provide is with the specific error that you're getting with this code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Webelement`, use `String` with `getText()`method so, it will give you the actual String. Not the Webelement.

**Note:** Instead of using `absolute` xpath, use `relative` xpath. For more details on `xpath` tutorial, refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).

```
String expectedtext="Summary";
String actualtext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/h3[text()='Summary']")).getText();
System.out.println(actualtext);

if (expectedtext.equalsIgnoreCase(actualtext))
 {
       System.out.println("User succesfully loggedIN");
 } 
 else 
 {
       System.out.println("Invalid credtendials!!");
 }
```

Comment: yes i followed the same code, but it doesn't verify this condition.
`if (expectedtext.equalsIgnoreCase(actualtext))
 {
       System.out.println("User succesfully loggedIN");
 } 
 else 
 {
       System.out.println("Invalid credtendials!!");
 }`

Comment: `<div class="page-title">
<h3 class="ng-binding">Summary</h3>
</div>`

Comment: What you mean else condition is not working??, If `If condition is execute` then `else` condition will not execute.

Comment: Did you get any error, while performing this code??

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's resolved your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-
String expectedtext="Summary";
String actualtext= null;

```
    actualtext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/ng-include/div/div/div[1]/div/h3")).gettext();
```