# In Selenium, if a step fails for a test case, is it possible to just report the failure and continue with remaining steps?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, ui-automation

In Selenium, if a step fails for a test case, is it possible to just report the failure and continue with remaining steps? Currently the execution halts if there is an exception. This is what my Test case looks like-

```
public class TC002_abc extends OpentapWrappers
{       

    @Test (description="Test")
    public void main() 
    {

        try
        {             
            WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);     
            VerifyTitle(Constant.HomePage_Title);  
            Click(HomePage.link_Login(driver), "Login Link");           
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains(Constant.LoginURL));    
            VerifyTextPopulated(CommunicationPref.lbl_EmailAddress_Input(driver), Constant.EmailAddress);       
            /* Validate Email Communications */                 
            Click(CommunicationPref.link_EditEmailCommunications(driver),"Edit Email Communications");
            VerifyText(CommunicationPref.lbl_UnCheckedEmailCommunications(driver), Constant.UnCheckedEmailCommunications_Text);
            Click(CommunicationPref.btn_EmailCommunicationsSave(driver), "Save");                           
            VerifyText(CommunicationPref.lbl_CheckedEmailCommunications(driver), Constant.CheckedEmailCommunications_Text);               
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Reporter.reportStep("NoSuchElementException" , "FAIL");         
        }
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass()
    {
        browserName="firefox";
        testCaseName = "TC002_abc";
        testDescription = "Test";
    }

}
```

Sample Method-

```
public static void VerifyTitle(String title){

    try
    {       

        if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title))
        {           
            Reporter.reportStep("Page is successfully loaded :"+title, "PASS");                     
        }
        else

            Reporter.reportStep("Page Title :"+driver.getTitle()+" did not match with :"+title, "FAIL");

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Reporter.reportStep("The title did not match", "FAIL");
    }

}
```

Comment: Just catch the exception that is thrown, if one of the steps does fail make sure that the other steps are not dependednent on that failed test as it could alter the results. You could try splitting your test into smaller tests that are more managable, meaning other tests can continue if one fails, each test should be able to run indepenedntly.

Comment: I am not talking about different TCs. Same test case, lets say if my 4th step fails the execution halts there and the rest of the steps are skipped. I want it to report the failure for 4th step and continue executing 5th one. Is it possible? Currently if an exception is thrown at 4th step, its being caught and failure reported but the execution doesn't continue.

Comment: The TCs are just for UI validation. So i dont want the run to stop in middle just cz one of the elements wasn't found on the page. Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: you need to put try catch blocks round each method(step), not the whole test

Comment: remove the try catch round the test, dont need it and its what causing your test to end

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Formatted the code.

Comment: tried removing the try catch from tc. Doesn't work

Comment: refer this link and try that way :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231994/need-to-verify-user-landed-on-correct-page-after-login/45232741#45232741

Comment: The issue in the mentioned linked isn't related to my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using TestNG, implement a Soft Assertion

```
public void VerifyTitle(String title)
{

     SoftAssert assertion = new SoftAssert();
     String returnedTitle = driver.getTitle();

     if (assertion.assertTrue(returnedTitle.contains(title)))
     {

          Reporter.reportStep("Page is successfully loaded :" + title, "PASS");

     } else
     {

         Reporter.reportStep("Page Title :" + driver.getTitle() + " did not match with :" + title, "FAIL");
     }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: if returns a boolean value and assertion void. So am getting error there- Cannot covert void to boolean

Answer (score 1):

> if a step fails for a test case, is it possible to just report the
> failure and continue with remaining steps?

Short answer: YES
Long answer: YES

Selenium is framework built on top of a test engine such as JUnit or TestNG. On those engines, if you do nothing, the tool will interpret as a pass. In other words, in the absence of an assertion, the engines will assume the test passed. Since Selenium is built on top of this, the same can be said about Selenium.  The code snippet below is a representation of what a Cucumber step looks like.

```
@When("my test step here")
public void myTestStep(...) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
            result = myTest(...);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log your exception (don't rethrow)
    }
    if (result) {
        // log your passing test
    } else {
        // log your failing test
        Assert.fail(); // This is what prevents subsequent steps to be executed. Remove it, and you should be able to continue to test.
}
```

For a JUnit or TestNG style method is basically the same. You may have an `@AfterClass` or `@AfterTest` hook that might handle telling the test framework to pass of fail test. **TYPICALLY**, passing assertions are implied (by not doing anything - i.e. executing an empty method). However, failing assertions are EXPLICIT and must be included somewhere. Just look for those `Assert.fail()` methods and remove them. A better alternative is to add a configurable property to your test suite that will turn this on or off.

```
    } else {
        // log your failing test
        if (skip_off) {
            Assert.fail(); // This is what prevents subsequent steps to be executed. Remove it, and you should be able to continue to test.
        }
}
```

In this context, `skip_off` is the value of Boolean property you might have stored in a configuration file that when set to true, it will skip enforcing fail assertions.